# How do I access this function from within another scope?

Tags: javascript, function

I am trying to develop a sdk for a client and the client should setar its data before loading the file with javascrip. The function is in global scope and my script is in another scope. How do I access customer data from another scope?

Global function

```js
    window.codeInit = function () {
        var init = {
            ID: "1234",
            elementStart: "#contentDiv"
        }
    };
```

Scope of where I want to access the function data

```js
(function(window){

//Access from here

})(window)
```

Comment: global variable

Comment: the `init` variable is only visible while actually within the `window.codeInit`, you'd need to make the function return it or store it in a variable outside of the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this

```
var init = {
    ID: "1234",
    elementStart: "#contentDiv"
}
window.codeInit = function() {
    console.log(init.ID);
};

(function(window){
    codeInit();
})(window)
```